# Check value of same column in all tables [Entity Framework]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have more than 100 tables in data base in which 60+ table's contain column called  `ShortCode nvarchar(12)` which represent globally unique code of that record.

Now is there any way to find that the `ShortCode` value eg. `AST_SHIP_FIRE` present in any of the table in database.

**Note**:`ShortCode` is user define.

currently I am try below code,it works but I have to code for all table.

```
if (entities.Table1.Any(x =>  x.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower() == a.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower()) 
{return false;}
else if(entities.Table2.Any(x => x.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower() == a.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower()))
{return false;}
else if( entities.Talble3.Any(x => x.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower() == a.ShortCode.Trim().ToLower()))
{return false;}
.
.
.
else
{
//insert code
}
```

I think there may be more efficient way.

Comment: That's hard because it's a _very unusual_ thing to do.  Why would you have a column that is unique across multiple tables?

Comment: I would create a new table with a single column and fill it with the ShortCode from all other tables. Use that table to check for uniqueness. Of course, you'll have to update it as new records are added\deleted\modified. That being said, i agree that checking for unique values across multiple tables in not a common scenario.

Comment: @Shahafo __create a new table with a single column__ I also agree with that and go through it.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft That code contain unique permission to do work at somewhere and the unique code will tag with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, maybe not very straightforward but lets do it!

First of all define an interface for `ShortCode` property and implement it by any entity that has it:

```
public interface ITableWithShortCode
{
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
}

public class Table1 : ITableWithShortCode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
}

public class Table2 : ITableWithShortCode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }
}
```

Now using power of `Reflection` you can write a method like this:

```
public bool IsExistShortCode(string shortCode)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        /* 
           find all tables that are defined in your DbContext and are implemented ITableWithShortCode like:
           public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
           public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
           ...
        */
        var properties = typeof(AppDbContext).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                && typeof(ITableWithShortCode).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]));

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var contextProp = (IQueryable<ITableWithShortCode>)property.GetValue(context);
            bool isExist = contextProp.Any(p => p.ShortCode == shortCode);
            if (isExist)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can do some optimization on this code, I prefered to keep it in its simplest state to show the idea. But in production, for example you can easily cache DbContext properties on startup and use it afterward